# Iterating Over List of Parsed Files Python

Tags: python, argparse

This program scans through a log file and finds faults and timestamps for the faults. The problem I am having with my program is finding a way to modify my program so that it can iterate over multiple files given via the command line and wildcard. In the state the code is now, it can accept a single file and build the dictionary with my my desired info successfully. I have been struggling finding a way to perform this with multiple files simultaneously. The goal is to able to enter into the command line the filename with a wildcard to parse files associated. For example on the command line after the executable I would enter, -f filename.*txt**. However, I cannot find a way to parse multiple files through my fault finder. I have been successful in parsing multiple files and proved it by printing out the list of files parsed. But when it comes to using multiple files and building the dictionary, I am stumped. I would like to use my program and have the same result as it would when parsing a singular file.

```
import sys
import argparse
_TIME_STAMP_LENGTH = 16
_FAULT_STRING_HEADER_LENGTH = 15
class FaultList():
    fault_dict = {}
    fault_dict_counter = {}

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.find_faults()
        print self.fault_dict
    def find_faults(self):
        with open(self.file) as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                fault_index = line.find("Fault Cache id")
                if(fault_index != -1):
                    time_stamp = line[:_TIME_STAMP_LENGTH]
                    fault_data = line[fault_index+_FAULT_STRING_HEADER_LENGTH:-11][:-1] #need the [:-1] to remove new line from string
                    self.handle_new_fault_found(fault_data, time_stamp)
    def handle_new_fault_found(self, fault, time_stamp):
        try:
            self.fault_dict[fault] = [fault]
            self.fault_dict[fault].append(int(time_stamp))
            self.fault_dict_counter[0] += 1
        except KeyError:
            self.fault_dict_counter[fault] = [1, [time_stamp]]
def main(file_names):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="file_names",
                        help="The binary file to be writen to flash")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    fault_finder = FaultList(args.file_names)
    args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Here is the output of dictionary when parsing a singular file

{'fault_01_17_00 Type:Warning': ['fault_01_17_00 Type:Warning', 37993146319], 'fault_0E_00_00 Type:Warning': ['fault_0E_00_00 Type:Warning', 38304267561], 'fault_05_01_00 Typ': ['fault_05_01_00 Typ', 38500887160]}

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your main question: Why are you using a class for this? Are you using Python 2?

Comment: It was just the way I decided to code it, I am using python 2.7

Comment: I know you coded it that way, I'm asking for the reason behind that choice... May I ask why you are using Python 2?

Comment: The reason I used a class was to learn how to parse using a class, no other reason besides that. Im using 2.7 because I haven't upgraded since starting to use python a few months ago.

Comment: _to learn how to parse using a class_ Huh, okay... Is that a thing? Regardless, I would really suggest upgrading to Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module for listing files.

```py
import os

# finds all files in a directory
files = [file for file in os.listdir('path of the files') if os.path.isfile(file)]

# filter them looking for files that end with 'txt'
txt_files = [file for file in files if file.endswith('txt')]
```